# Getting error use of undeclared identifier "value" when assigning parameter to variable

Tags: ios

When I assign value to age, I get this error:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
{
    int age;
} 
-(void)setAge;   
@end
```

I tried to use `self.age`, yet it did not work

Here is my .m file:

```
@implementation Person 
-(void)setAge(int)value
{ 
    age = value;
}    
@end
```

I tried several differnet things. ..I get this error when I type this: age = value; do you know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
-(void)setAge:(int)value;
```

In the header file because the current method specification you have there doesn't have a parameter.

Your method in the implementation should also have the same spec as it's missing a colon currently.

Answer (score 0):

You have actually declared one method (`-setAge`) and implemented another (`-setAge:`, note the colon). You should really declare `age` as a property and avoid explicit ivars as much as possible. Also, I hope you have properly formatted the class in your real code.

```
@interface Person : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic) int age;

@end

@implementation Person 

-(void)setAge:(int)value
{ 
    _age = value;
}

@end
```

Note that it is no longer necessary to explicitly `@synthesize` properties, and they automatically synthesize with an underscored ivar.

Comment: If a property is used, there is no point to the `setAge:` method at all. And in the posted code, there is a missing colon in the `setAge` implementation.

Comment: Sure, as it is, it is just an academic exercise, but there is often cause for a custom implementation. And I noticed the missing colon, but the OP seemed to imply his code compiled, so I assume that was just a copy-and-paste error.

Comment: I agree there are plenty of reasons for custom setters. But based on the OP's code, this isn't one of them.